# Prove $S_n \rightarrow 0 \iff |S_n| \rightarrow 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, absolute-value

Just a quick and supposedly simple question which I don't understand how to do.

How would you prove $$S_n\to 0 \iff|S_n|\to 0$$

Comment: What is $S_{n}$?

Comment: Hint: Write down the definition of the limit. What does $S_n \to 0$ exactly mean?

Comment: even $S_n^2\to 0$ iff $S_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just playing with definition
$$
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n=0&\Longleftrightarrow
(\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\quad\forall n>N\implies|S_n-0|\leq\varepsilon)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow
(\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\quad\forall n>N\implies||S_n|-0|\leq\varepsilon)
\Longleftrightarrow\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|S_n|=0\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 4):

One way is obvious, for the other way use that 
$|x|=0\iff x=0$  and that $| \cdot | $ is continuous.

Or more elementary use 
$$-|S_n|\leq S_n \leq |S_n|$$

Answer (score 3):

If $a_n\to 0$ so $$\forall~\epsilon>0,~\exists N\in\Bbb N,~~n>N \Longrightarrow |a_n|<\epsilon$$ This equals to $$\forall~\epsilon>0,~\exists N\in\Bbb N,~~n>N \Longrightarrow \big||a_n||<\epsilon$$ This equals to $|a_n|\to 0$

Comment: Yay for 15K! That was quick! +1

Answer (score 1):

$-|S_n|\le S_n\le|S_n|$

So if $|S_n|\to 0 $ as $n\to \infty $ then $S_n\to 0$ also.

Comment: Please either name or prove the result you are using for this.

Comment: @TaraB squeeze theorem?

Comment: Abhra Abir Kundu, did you prove the converse?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim S_n= 0 \iff |\lim S_n|= 0 \iff \lim|S_n|= 0$$

Intuitively, you can take $\lim$ in and out of absolute values because $f(x) = |x|$ is continuous.