# Prove: If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n| = 0$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

> Using the squeeze theorem, prove the following:
>
> If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n| = 0$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = 0$.

Let $f(x) = |a_n|$. Let $g(x) = a_n$ such that $\forall x : g(x) \leq f(x)$. How do I continue this proof using the squeeze theorem? I want to construct a function $h(x)$ that lies in between those two functions.

Comment: Another question about the same equivalence is: [Prove $S_n \rightarrow 0 \iff |S_n| \rightarrow 0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311131/prove-s-n-rightarrow-0-iff-s-n-rightarrow-0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint : $-|x|\le x\le |x|{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I am interested in how you arrived to this conclusion. (Thought process)?

Comment: Well I didn't really have a thought process. It was kind of mechanical. But I guess you could think of it that way: I wanted to squeeze $x$ between $l(|x|)$ and $r(|x|)$ where $l$ and $r$ are continuous functions and $l(0)=0=r(0)$ so that I can use the squeeze theorem. And so I started with simple functions: functions of the form $x\mapsto \alpha x$ and found the solutions $l(y)=-y$ and $r(y)=y$.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer uses the [squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Alternatively, note that
$$
|a_n-0|=||a_n|-0|\tag{1}
$$

Now if you unwrapping the definition of limits, the consequence is immediate by (1).