# Proof verification: If $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Hey I was just working on this problem,

Prove: If $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

I am not quite sure how to go about it. I was wondering if anyone had any tips on starting this proof?

---

EDIT: I think I got the answer but I wanted to check it.

Proof: Let $ > 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0$.
Then, by definition, $||a_n|-0| \leq  $ for $n \geq N$. Since $||a_n|-0| = |a_n-0|$ we can say $|a_n-0| \leq $ for $n \geq N$. Therefore, by definition $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

Does this look alright?

Comment: Hint: $|a_n-0|=\Big||a_n|-0\Big|$

Comment: Important: what do $a_n$ denote? Are they real numbers or complex numbers? I say this because we can't help you without this information.

Comment: a_n denotes a list of real numbers.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Write out what it means to say $a_n \to a$ in terms of $|a-a_n|$.

Comment: [Prove: If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n| = 0$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/505020)

Comment: Ok I think I might have something. I was going to begin by letting ǫ>0. Then there exists some N in the natural numbers such that |a_n-0|<ǫ for all n>=N. Then, since |a_n - 0| = ||a_n|-0| we can say  ||a_n|-0| < ǫ. Also sorry about my notation being strange, this is the first time I have used stack exchange and I'm not sure how to make the special characters.

Comment: Wait actually I just realized I was proving the wrong thing and that I need to use the fact that we are already given 0 as the limit of |a_n| as it approaches infinity.

Comment: @MATStudent: can you add all those words to your post?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove: If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n| = 0$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505020/prove-if-lim-n-rightarrow-inftya-n-0-then-lim-n-rightarrow-inftya)

Comment: @mrsamy will do, thank you all for your help!

Comment: @Crostul It is answering the same question but I don't really understand it the way it is explained in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your newly added proof is correct. Although, it may be better if you reword it slightly.

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=0$ and let $\epsilon>0$. By definition, there exists a positive integer $N$, such that for every $n\ge N$,
$
||a_n|-0|\le\epsilon
$
But $||a_n|-0|=|a_n-0|$ for each $n$. So it follows that
$$
|a_n-0|\le\epsilon
$$
whenever $n\ge N$, which implies by definition that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

The key step in your proof is the observation that $||a_n|-0|=|a_n-0|$.

---

Alternatively, you may observe that $-|a_n|\le a_n\le |a_n|$ and apply the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: ok great thanks!